# Check if either column is null using insole function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I would like to check if either of the column has null in it using the `isnull` function but it doesn't seem to work... When I set either of the fields to none it still returns false

```
$result = mysql_query("select Apps.Email from Apps");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

My `if` statement:

```
if(is_null($row["Person1"], $row["Person2"])){
// stuff here
}
```

It works fine when I change it to:

```
if (is_null($row["Person1"])
```

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*` functions. These are depricated

Comment: `is_null` only takes in [one documented argument](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)...

Comment: @sjagr any alternative then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use or logic.

```
if(is_null($row["Person1"]) || is_null($row["Person2"])){
// stuff here
}
```

Or whatever the or symbol is in php.